# Connection of the model table with users (standard login module). Django, Python

Tags: python, django

I do not know if I have a good title this post, but I'm explaining what I mean.

I have a standard login module in django, I want my users to display only their own cookies. How can I connect users(cooks) inside in my model?

```
class Cookies(models.Model):
    """My Cookies"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photo = models.FileField()
    next_information = models.ManyToManyField(Someone)
    'user = ?' <-- how to assign a cook as a user to Cookies
```

Then I would like to filter my users(cooks) in the views.py (who added own a new cookie to the table), so that after logging in only the cookies created by a given chef will be displayed.

Using in view.py

```
Cookies.objects.filter('user = ?')...
```

To summarize, how to connect standard users with a model in the database. 
I have 10 chefs and everyone has their own cakes. In views.py, only the cookies of the cook are shown.

Thank you very much for help. I apologize as I wrote this in an unintelligible way. If something is unclear (in my problem), I will try to explain it better.

**views.py**

```
def cookies_list(request):
    cookies = Cookies.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = { 'cookies':cookies }
    return render(request, 'account/templates.html', context)
```

**templates.html**

```
{% block content %}
{% for cookies in cookies_list  %}
<label for="file-1">
<span class="text-white">Hello world</span>
</label>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'media_app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app_rama.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app_rama.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Miejsce szukania pliekow statycznych w django
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
# konie. Kod szuka plikow statycznych w folderze glownym, a nie tylko w naszych aplikacjach.

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_app/media')
```

Comment: You would use a ForeignKey, exactly as you would for any other link between models.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know how to use it for other models e.g 'reporter = models.ForeignKey(My_class_above, on_delete=models.CASCADE)' but what will it be 'My_class_above' for the standard login model (django.contrib.auth)? I use the Django built-in login module.

Comment: You use `"auth.User"` or `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the foreignkey relation

```
class Cookies(models.Model):
"""My Cookies"""
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  photo = models.FileField()
  next_information = models.ManyToManyField(Someone)
  user = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
```

inside the view you can filter the cookies,

```
cookeis = Cookies.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but when creating the view, 'templates' returns an error:
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user', do I have to use some special formatting?

Comment: I added to the main content views.py and template.html

Comment: can you add you middleware class of settings files, in that if MIDDLEWARE is there then change that key word to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Comment: make MIDDLEWARE to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Comment: which django version you are using

Comment: (2, 1, 2, 'final', 0)-django version, you mean changing my class name from 'MIDDLEWARE' to 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' and nothing more? (Do not change anything yet inside?)

Comment: yaa, try with that

Comment: Did not help, after changing to 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' the error is shown in each tab ''WSGIRequest' object has no attribute...'. Before changes only for the template rendered by my view 'cookies_list' .

Comment: somehow middle ware class is not getting call

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will look for a solution. I added the entire settings.py file,I think I have some lost module ... inside this file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ForeignKey`. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

> Instead of referring to User directly, you should reference the user model using django.contrib.auth.get_user_model(). This method will return the currently active user model – the custom user model if one is specified, or User otherwise.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

class Cookies(models.Model):
    """My Cookies"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photo = models.FileField()
    next_information = models.ManyToManyField(Someone)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```